# What is correct understandanding of Cassandra tunable consistency?

Tags: cassandra

It is said *consistency level* **N** defines number of replicas needed to acknowledge every read and write operation.The bigger that number, the more consistent result we have.

If we define that parameter as **N (N < M/2)**, where *M* is cluster size, does it mean the following situation is possible :

1 data center. two concurrent writes happened successfully(they updated the same key with different values)? 
And consequently, two subsequent concurrent reads return different values for the same key? Am i correct?

Comment: The coordinator will send the write request to all live nodes that own the key. So one write will overwrite the other. Exceptions occur if some of the nodes are offline. Check this: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlClientRequestsWrite.html

Comment: @ernest_k i intentionally noted that we tuned consistency level setting

Comment: Yes. Even if `N = 2` and `M = 10` and the key is owned by `5` nodes, the coordinator will still send the write request to all 5 nodes, according to the docs. The consistency only affects the success of the write when the coordinator can't get a response from `N` nodes owning the key (before it sends the update to them). Consistency level doesn't affect *how many of the 5 nodes will receive the write*, all nodes that own the key will be updated. Your scenario may only cause problems if the 2 coordinators can only physically talk to just 2 our of 5 each.

Comment: @ernest_k ah, so the consistency level parameter only tells how many acknowledges coordinator receives from replicas before sending response to user?

Comment: Yes, that's how I understand the documentation.

Comment: So if it's a concern always write with QUORUM

Comment: @ernest_k interesting fact : in case of read operation, cassandra ask one replica for value, and ask other replicas(based on *consistency level*) for just hash. It is sufficient to assure value is equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can tune consistency based on requirements for read and writes. Quorum is recommended consistency level for Cassandra for single DC. we can calculate from below Quorum =N/2+1 where N is number of replica. Consistency we can set from below command
CONSISTENCY [level]

For more details on tunable consistency please refer below.

https://medium.com/dugglabs/data-consistency-in-apache-cassandra-part-1-7aee6b472fb4
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlAboutDataConsistency.html

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshConsistency.html

Answer (score 1):

In Cassandra it is highly possible that different client applications are updating value of same key on different nodes. You can restrict this always by tuning your consistency level.

**Consistency Level always depends on Replication Factor decided by you.**

If RF=3 from 5 nodes DC, then Consistency level QUORUM or LOCAL_QUORUM means 2 nodes out of 3 which are having replica.

Any of the below combination should give you correct data, after tuning:

```
WRITE=ALL READ=ONE  
WRITE=ONE READ=ALL  
WRITE=LOCAL_QUORUM READ=LOCAL_QUORUM
```

You can tune consistency level in your application, as per load of the application.

According to me, Number 3 LOCAL_QUORUM should work better, As sometimes a node can be under high load or maybe is down. Your application will not get affected.

In case, you have more writes than READ; WRITE CL=ALL will make your application slow.